# Many small dbqueries - necessary?

Tags: mysql

Say I want to make a statistic page over working hours in a company.

I want to display: "Longest shift", "Shortest shift", "Most hours", "Least hours"

Then with my limited knowledge I'd have to make 4 different dbqueries:

**Longest shift** -> ORDER BY Shiftlength DESC
**Shortest shift** -> ORDER BY Shiftlength ASC
**Most hours** -> GROUP BY PERSON ORDER BY totalhours DESC
**Least hours** -> GROUP BY PERSON ORDER BY totalhours ASC

But for some reason I have gotten it into my head that this is a bit excessive and hard on the server. 
Is my way the correct way?

Comment: Benchmark it...no seriously, just try it.

Comment: Without knowing your table structure, you can certainly reduce this to two queries where, in each case, you get the first and last value of the results (assuming you're using another language, such as PHP, to parse the results) - The two queries would be to get shift lengths and total hours by person

Comment: actually, in sql only, you can, for each query, get the `MIN` and `MAX` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the MAX() and MIN() operators in MySQL

```
SELECT MAX(shiftlength)

SELECT MIN(shifthours)
```

Rich :)

Comment: But what if shiftlength and shifthours aren't DB fields, but "AS" fields as in "Count(blabla) AS shifthours"

Comment: @Brian: select Max(Count(Blablala)) as shifthours from x group by id

Answer (score 0):

Small queries are **not** hard on the server.

If you don't use dynamic SQL, but use paramaterized queries (PDO) instead MySQL will cache the query and can recall the results from memory instantly.

Answer (score 0):

The Most & Least hours you can reduce that to one query, aslong as your `GROUP BY` syntax groups all the other records together.

```
SELECT
    MAX(totalhours) AS MostHours,
    MIN(totalhours) AS LeastHours
  FROM x
  GROUP BY Person
```

You could do the same with the first two if you can find a good `GROUP BY` syntax.

- EDIT:

After your comment I would consider just doing one query and sorting the results in PHP, which should be pretty fast, but it might be that your multiple queries are faster. So thus you'd have to benchmark first.

Comment: But then how do I get php to show me two tables: One where it's ordered by MAX and another where it's ordered by MIN?

Comment: I thought you only wanted to display the results, as one value.